# How to justify content on navbar (Bootstrap 5)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

I currently have a very minimal navbar set up with Bootstrap 5.
With navigation bars, there is both the 'navbar-brand' and nav links.

I want my brand/logo to be all the way on the far left, while all the navbar-nav links to be all the way to the right.

This could be achieved with flexbox and `justify-content-between`

However I have 0 clue where the navbar flex properties come into play, so therefore I am not sure where or what to change to achieve this effect

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/brand.png"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
            <div class="navbar-nav">
                <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want ? Indeed, `justify-content-between`  is very useful for that. You have to use this style for the parent div and to put the children elements you want inside it.

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav
      class="navbar d-flex justify-content-between fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light p-2"
    >
      <a class="navbar-brand align-self-center" href="#"><img src="images/brand.png" /></a>
      <button
        class="navbar-toggler align-self-center"
        type="button"
        data-bs-toggle="collapse"
        data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup"
        aria-expanded="false"
        aria-label="Toggle navigation"
      >
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav text-end pe-1">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```